# Are these root buds forming on my grape stems?

Tags: roots

While rooting a couple grape stems in water, these white buds have formed on my stems, what are they?
I have a picture to upload but even though my file size says 581.8KB which the online converter of KB to MiB says that equals
0.5548477MiB, it still won't upload my image with an error message saying that my image is too large - over 2MiB.

Please help me communicate fully with you.
Thank you.

Comment: I tried to save the same photo using different formats, and I noticed that PNG format uses the least amount of bytes. You may still need to crop the image though, since camera/mobile files tend to be large due to their resolution. You may also download the photo to your PC, view it on screen and use the print-screen feature to select a smaller-sized photo.

Comment: You can use Irfanview (free) to resize/resample.